# B64 encode/decode handling in case data is not in multiple of 3

Tags: c++, base64, decode, encode

While using B64 decode it doesn't remove the padded extra bytes added in Base64 encoding ?

Consider the scenario where I am giving data of size 50(not in multiple of 3) to the encode function this returns encoded data of size 68.
While using decode for the encoded data(input of 68 bytes) then decode function returns 51 bytes data, which I was expecting as zero.

How base 64 encode/decode should be handled properly when the data size is not in multiple of 3 ?

I have used open source Base64 encode/decode library which is compliant with RFC4648.properly

Answer (score 2):

Base64 encoding uses a special marker at the end to indicate that padding was added.

It *always* generates a multiple of four output characters, each corresponding to three octets of input data except possibly the last one.

For that last one, if there are only two octets left, it encodes those into three characters (each taking six bits = eighteen, sixteen bits real data and two bits of junk) then adds a special padding `=` character to give four characters.

If there is only *one* octet left, it encodes that into two characters (sixteen bits, twelve bits real data and four bits of junk) then adds a special padding `==` character to give four characters.

Hence, during decoding, it's the number of `=` characters at the end that tells you how to handle the last section so as to end up with exactly the same data you encoded.

In other words, the input data `AAAA` (each `A` holding bits `abcdef`) gives:

```
decoding input: abcdef abcdef abcdef abcdef
                             |
                             V
        output: abcdefab cdefabcd efabcdef
```

For a slightly short block `AAA=` (irrelevant bits being `+` and padding bits being `=`):

```
decoding input: abcdef abcdef abcd++ ======
                             |
                             V
        output:      abcdefab cdefabcd
```

And a very short block `AA==`:

```
decoding input: abcdef ab++++ ====== ======
                             |
                             V
        output:           abcdefab
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation, But still the example given by you wasn't clear to me, like for the first case where input data is 'AAAA' if it is divided in group of three characters then 'AAA' will be encoded into four digits and for the last 'A' encoder might add some extra zeroes in RHS side and then encode it and append '==' at the output. Or might be I am understanding it wrong, Can you please make it much clear.

Answer (score 0):

So here '=' is used as a padding character for base64 encoding.
By determining number of '=' characters at the end of encoded data I can figure out whether the input data is in multiple of 3 or not.
In other words if there is '='(single equal to) character then possibly two octets left and if there is '==' then single octet was left in the last group of three characters.